# Stack Exchange users' page

Tags: support, stack-exchange, users-page

I can't open the page https://stackexchange.com/users.

What is the reason for that? I *can* visit individual users:

- https://stackexchange.com/users/1
- https://stackexchange.com/users/2
- https://stackexchange.com/users/3
- https://stackexchange.com/users/4

If there are  problems listing users according to reputations, names, or any other means, it would be better to list users ordered by user id.

SE moderators were well known that this is not really important at all.

What is the reason for the https://stackexchange.com/users page not working?

I don't think it's a feature request (though I would like the page to work), I just was curious about this.

Comment: I believe the network profile is still going through some development, and most likely at some point there will be network wide users page, listing the network profiles. Just my opinion though, nothing official but worth keeping this post as reference. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no users listing page on the central Stack Exchange site.

The page gives a 404, Not Found, not a server error. It is not broken, just Not There. It just was never built, and that's probably because there is little point in ranking users from widely different Stack Exchange sites against one another.

Answer (score 2):

The page doesn't have any Users list.

[image: screenshot]

It is **not an error**.